# HTML validator message: element <li> is not allowed

Tags: html

I have list:

```
<td ><a href="#"><?php  echo $meniu['lovos']; ?></a>
<ul>
<?php
$result = mysql_query("SELECT baldo_id, kategorija,pavadinimas_lt, pavadinimas_en, pavadinimas_lv, pavadinimas_ru FROM baldas WHERE kategorija = 'sofoslovos'") or die(mysql_error());
        if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
                while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
                     {
                 echo'              
                <li><a href="index.php?id=baldas&amp;id2='.$row['baldo_id'].'">';if ($_SESSION['lang']==lt)
                                {echo''.$row['pavadinimas_lt'].'</a>';}
                                elseif ($_SESSION['lang']==en)
                                {echo''.$row['pavadinimas_en'].'</a>';}
                                elseif ($_SESSION['lang']==ru)
                                {echo''.$row['pavadinimas_ru'].'</a>';}
                                elseif ($_SESSION['lang']==lv)
                                {echo''.$row['pavadinimas_lv'].'</a>';}
                                else {echo''.$row['pavadinimas_lt'].'</a>
                </li>';}
    }}?>
</ul>
</td>
```

HTML code:

```
<td><a href="#">Komplektai</a>
<ul>        
                <li><a href="index.php?id=baldas&amp;id2=32">yy</a>         
                <li><a href="index.php?id=baldas&amp;id2=33">yy</a>             
                <li><a href="index.php?id=baldas&amp;id2=67">rrr</a>                
                <li><a href="index.php?id=baldas&amp;id2=71">jj</a>   
</ul>
</td>
```

And when I do validation I keep getting error message:

> document type does not allow element "li" here; missing one of "ul",
>   "ol", "menu", "dir" start-tag

But I don't get it. There is both `<ul>` and `<li>` elements on my list.

Comment: please check and post the generated html, not the php code.

Comment: Could you also please post the HTML that's being output by your PHP?

Comment: You sure that's the relevant code? Maybe you have stray `<li>` somewhere else.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `li` elements are only being closed in the final `else` of the conditional. Make sure they get closed in each case.

Comment: Hmmm… the end tag for `<li>` is optional though … maybe the question was mis-tagged and should be *XHTML*.

Comment: I actually didn't know that :) The question then is what doctype the OP is validating for.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are trying to validate a PHP program instead of an HTML document.

Run the program, then validate the HTML it outputs.

(If that isn't the case, then don't show us the PHP, show us the final HTML).